# Unable to resolve module react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes

Tags: react-native

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "BStore",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.5",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.11.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }    
}
```

I am getting this error `Unable to resolve module`react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes`

any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Stop downvoting. I have the same issue on `"react-native": "0.58.4"` -> `Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` from `C:\Projects\some-project-name\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\createAnimatedComponent.js`: Module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` does not exist in the Haste module map`

Answer (score 10):

Had same issue.

As I find out expo 32.0.5 and react-native 0.58.3 are not compatible. So expo react-native fork should be used.

To install it you can use command

`npm install --save react-native@https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.1.tar.gz`

Comment: I get this error with expo 32.0.6 and react-native@0.58.3, and I get another error with the react-native fork which uses babel-core@6.26.3. Is there any good combination of versions of expo, react-native, and babel-core? My package.json looks like https://gist.github.com/dancancro/8f43d9d50716520ec57276ac122e6d93

Comment: Im using expo 32.0.6 and react-native https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 4):

You have to **read the error-message carefully**. I've the same issue, mine was:

> Unable to resolve module
>   `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes` from
>   `/APP/node_modules/react-native-render-html/src/HTMLUtils.js`:
>   Module `react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes`
>   does not exist in the Haste module map

So the 3rd Party Library `react-native-render-html` cause the error, because it try to use ViewStylePropTypes.

In case of **@adrian-moisa**: For you it's `react-native-reanimated`.
Don't know what the cause was for the ThreadOpener, he didn't post an usable error-message.

Fact is, that `ViewStylePropTypes` was removed up from `react-native 0.58`

**compare:** 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/v0.57.8/Libraries/Components/View
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/v0.58.0/Libraries/Components/View

So the solution is to figure out, which 3rd-Party Component cause the error, and look if there is an upgrade from the maintainer, or yourself have to patch it (e.g. with [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package))

Answer (score 0):

This combo works for me:

```
"expo": "^31.0.4",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the instructions from [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52), with what worked for me:

Here’s how to upgrade your app to Expo SDK 32.0.6 from 31.0.0:

- Close your Expo CLI server In app.json, change sdkVersion to "32.0.1"
  In package.json, change these dependencies:

  - react-native to "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.1.tar.gz"
  - expo to "^32.0.6"
  - react to "16.8.6" — (this exact version)
  - react-navigation to "^3.9.1" (if you use it — this is also optional, you don’t have to update it to use the newest SDK. If you
    choose to, make sure you read the changelog for breaking changes, and
    see this upgrade guide for upgrading from v2 to v3.)
  - jest-expo to "^32.0.0" (if you use it)
  - sentry-expo to "~1.11.2" (if you use it) Delete your project’s node_modules directory and run npm install again (or use Yarn, we
    love Yarn) Run expo start -c Update the Expo app on your phones from
    the App Store / Google Play. expo-cli will automatically update your
    apps in simulators. Make sure to check the breaking changes section
    of this post! If you built a standalone app previously, remember that
    you will need to create a new build in order to update the SDK
    version. Run expo build:iosand/or expo build:android when you are
    ready to do a new build for submission to stores. If you are planning
    to submit your iOS app to the App Store, you must upgrade to Xcode 10
    in order to do so.